# How can we reject a window containing an outlier during rolling average using python?

Tags: python, outliers, moving-average

The problem that I am facing is how i can reject a window of 10 rows if one or many of the rows consist of an outlier while computing rolling average using python pandas?

For clarification:

```
df = df['speed'].rolling(10).mean() 
outlier_lower_bound = 0
outlier_upper_bound = 15

df.max()
```

Now how do I reject/ not consider the average value of those 10 period window if it consists an outlier?

The end goal is to get the max moving average without accounting/ considering the window of 10 period if it contains an outlier Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain your idea more? Also, if there is any code involved, it's a good idea to post it.

Comment: You can apply [this technique of getting the rolling value then filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964363/filtering-out-outliers-in-pandas-dataframe-with-rolling-median) but use mean rather than median

Comment: For clarification: @Anwarvic 

df = df['speed'].rolling(10).mean()

Now how do I reject/ not consider the average value of those 10 period window if it consists an outlier? The lower bound is 0 and the upper bound is 15

The end goal is to
get the max moving average without accounting/ considering the window of 10 period if it contains an outlier

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do fix your issue in just one line like so:

```py
_filter = lambda x: float("inf") if x > outlier_upper_bound or x < outlier_lower_bound else x

df["speed"].apply(_filter).rolling(10).mean().dropna()
```

The idea behind my code can be understood in these steps:

- I create a lambda function called `_filter` that converts any value outside your boundaries into `inf`.
- When applying `mean` over a window that has `inf` in it, the result will be `Nan`.
- Finally, I drop all `Nan` values which will mimic the same effect.